# Equation with binomial coefficient (coefficients are fractional)

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve/approximate $x$ in the following equation:
$$\binom{x\cdot \log_2n}{\frac{x\cdot \log_2n}{2}} = n,$$ where $n$ is a natural number.
Obviously $x$ is a decreasing function of $n$ and for $n=2$, $x=2$.
But besides that and some hardcoded trials, I do not know how can I proceed. Some help here would be really awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Set $2N=\log_2 n$ giving the nicer looking formula $\binom{x2N}{xN}=e^{2N}$ then use the classical approximation for the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) :$\binom{2k}{k} \approx \dfrac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$.

Comment: What do you want to do with your equation?  You won't get to solve it in closed form, but the standard numerical methods should work fine.

Comment: ... sorry, not $e^{2N}$ but $2^{2N}$ which is (interestingly !) $4^N$. At the end of the calculations, take the logarithls of both sides...

Comment: Please share with us why are you interested with such strange non-integer indices. This site is based on "exchanges" as indicated in its name...

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for your reply, I want to calculate the number of logn binary sequences with same 0s and 1s such that it is equal to n. I think for my purpose it is enough that x belongs to the interval (1, 2]